# map data download (Open street map) in MIF format

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap

i can download openstreet map data for whole planet http://planet.openstreetmap.org/
http://planet.openstreetmap.org/planet/2014/planet-140910.osm.bz2
from this link.but this link give only osm or pbf format.
i need the map data in mif format. any link or any solution will be highly appreciate.
thanks in advance

Comment: Why doesn't your converter work for the whole planet? Do you need the whole planet or would an [extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) be sufficient?

Comment: I need whole planet data in mif format.

the converter(osm to mif{https://code.google.com/p/osm2mif/}) does not work....It hang in the middle of conversion.
I think because of this size is huge.

Comment: Are you sure that it hangs? Maybe it just takes a lot of time. And if you [search the OSM wiki for mif](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/index.php?search=mif) you will find multiple pages about other tools being able to read/write mif files.

Comment: I can't convert the data. May be my windows pc(Intel Pentium R 2.13GHz Ram 2GB) not capable to process this huge data.
i will be really happy if anyone give me .mif formatted Map data of whole world.

Comment: Crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/36897/whole-planet-map-in-mif-format